# How to execute shell command in Groovy and get the return code $?

Tags: shell, groovy, return-value

I can't get the return code (not the output or error) from executing a shell script within Groovy.

For all what I tried, it either ask me to escape or just print the $? instead of give me 1 or 0.

groovy: 75: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 75, column 24.

Below are solutions I tried, all don't work.

```
println "../src/check_job_log.s ${it}.log".execute().text
println "Check log ${it}.log completed"

//assert ("echo \$?".execute().text == "1")
//output = """echo $?""".execute().text
println(['echo', '$?'].execute().text)

// below is code for  @that other guy
//def process = "echo hello world".execute()
def process = "../src/check_job_log.s ${it}.log".execute()
print "Output: " + process.text
print "Exit code: " + process.exitValue()

Output: Exit code: 01
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Process.exitValue()` instead of (or in addition to) `.text`:

```
def process = "echo hello world".execute()
print "Output: " + process.text
print "Exit code: " + process.exitValue()
```

Comment: $ksh ../src/check_job_log.s sb_sp_get_ucd_test.sql.log
$echo $?
0

Comment: Your code output is: Output: Exit code: 01. But as you can see from above the output from the command line is: 0. Why is this 01 and 0 different?

Comment: The output from my code should be `Output: hello world`, `Exit code: 0`. Are you getting something else?

Comment: I replace your hello world with my code, there is no ouput that's correct, but the exit code (01) is different from I run the same script from command line which is 0. I also tested with your code, the exit code is 01, not 0.

Comment: Good bless to groovy

Comment: In some cases, this might need `process.waitFor()` in order to wait for the process to end and then access its exit value. Not waiting for the process to end first before accessing `process.exitValue()` will end with `Caught: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited`

Answer (score 0):

Why these command has different output?

```
$../src/check_job_log.s dml_ucd_test.sql.log
/iiss/prod/sql>
$echo $?
1
/iiss/prod/sql>
$../src/check_job_log.s dml_ucd_test.sql.log | echo $?
0
ops@uaiisst3:/iiss/prod/sql>
$
```