# setting context in odi mapping objects

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-data-integrator

Due to project requirement we need to import the project mappings & other objects from a different server. But we found that all the mapping context becomes undefined.

I am trying to write a groovy program to set the context at a bulk. I have written the below code but somehow the `interfaceList` is empty and thus unable to perform `odiInterface.setOptimizationContext(context);`.

Below is my code. For brevity I haven't mentioned the packages stmt.

```java
def all the variables like url,driver,schema etc
def all variables like MasterInfo, auth, transaction, etc 

def OdiContext context = ((IOdiContextFinder) odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiContext.class)).findByCode("CTX_ANN1_S4")
for (p in odiProjectList) {
    if (p.getName() == "PrjDemo_TA") {
        def OdiFolderList = p.getFolders()
        for (f in OdiFolderList) {
            if (f.getName() == "TrgDemoMod_Comn_TA_S4") {
                // def OdiInterfaceList2 = f.getInterfaces()                
                // def OdiMappingList = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().findAll( Mapping.class)
                def OdiInterfaceList = ((IOdiInterfaceFinder) odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiInterface.class)).findByProject(projectCode, folderName)

                for (m in OdiInterfaceList2) {
                    println(m.getName() + "|" + m.getClass()) //+ "|" + m.getParent()   + "|" + m.getFolder() )
                    m.setOptimizationContext(context)
                }
                tm.commit(txnStatus)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line which initializes `OdiInterfaceList` is not throwing any error nor populating desired interface lists of all the interfaces within a folder.
So `m.setOptimizationContext(context)` is not executed.

If i substitute that line with:

```java
def OdiMappingList = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().findAll( Mapping.class)
```

within a `for ... loop` i can able to access the mappings but I don't know how to set its context `OdiMappingList` as `setOptimizationContext` is an interface's  method.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unable to reproduce your case as I don't have the environment to test it, but I still think I can help.

First, I refactored your code so its more groovy:

```java
def OdiContext context = ((IOdiContextFinder) odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiContext.class)).findByCode("CTX_ANN1_S4")

// Looking for the project
def prjDemo = odiProjectList.find { it.name == "PrjDemo_TA" }
assert prjDemo : "Unable to find ODI project"

//Getting the Mappings
def mappingList = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().findAll( Mapping.class)
assert ! mappingList.toList().empty : "Mappings not found"

// Printing interfaces
mappingList.each {
    it.setDefaultContext(context as IContext)
}
```

With those asserts, you may be able to know more in detail where your code may be really failing.

I noticed that `IOdiInterfaceFinder` is [marked as deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/project/finder/IOdiInterfaceFinder.html), so it might not play well with Oracle 12c. Check your versions.

Probably it would be better if you try to replace that deprecated code with a more updated version. I found some similar code to yours in [this page](http://odiexperts.com/automatically-add-interfacesscenarios-to-new-odipackage-using-odi-sdk/), so it might be useful.

**UPDATE**:
Updated the code to use `Mapping` class. As it has `setDefaultContext(IContext ctx)` method and `OdiContext` implements `IContext`, maybe it might work.

Comment: Heartiest thanks Lepe that you hv modified code in a marvelous way that i could get 2 know things like toList(), assert etc.But still  interfaceList is empty & assert becomes true:
def OdiInterfaceList = finder.findByProject(projectCode, folderName)
. Now if I use Mapping objects i cn able 2 access it but as it does not have any setOptimizationContext(), im again on  ground-0 seeking resolutions for 2 open qstns. 1.how to  set context for all mappings? 2.regenerate all scenarios in a batch frm mappings

Comment: My Odi version is 12.1.3 & im using odi groovy editor to write & run the code

Comment: @Sukhen_sql : I have modified the code using `Mapping` objects instead of `OdiInterface` objects. I don't have any way to test it, but it might help in any way. I have checked [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/Mapping.html) and so far is all I get.

Comment: @Sukhen_sql : Are both servers running 12.1.3 ?

Comment: Have you checked `OdiModel.getReverseContext()` and `OdiModel.setReverseContext(OdiContext pContext)` ? [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/model/OdiModel.html#getReverseContext())

Comment: mappingList.each {
      print (it.name)
     def OdiContext context2 =   it.getReverseContext()      // it.getDefaultContext ()  neither of the method working Lepe- No signature of method: oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping.getReverseContext() is applicable for argument types: () values: [].  Also it.setDefaultContext( context as  IContext) , i think is not working as expected as this context object is from OdiContext, but setDefaultContext() needs an obj. of IContext :-(  .... Like unix ,is there any way in groovy to check the excn status of last command ?

Comment: @Sukhen_sql: I see. You need to find a way to convert  `oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping` (is what mappingList returns) into `oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel` which has the `getReverseContext` method. I think it may work if you use `.setReverseContext` (not `setDefaultContext`). About your question, read [how to check the exit status of last command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655206/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-groovy-and-get-the-return-code). Unless you are doing a system call, I don't see how it can be useful though.